# Tailwind group:focus-within class not working in Safari

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css

I have the following multi select dropdown component in Blazor and seems like group-focus-within is not working when I test it out in Safari. I cannot select any values from the dropdown that opens up.

```
@inherits InputBase<List<IdFund.Common.Data.DTOs.DealAssignedUserDTO>>


<div
    @onclick:stopPropagation="true"
    @onclick:preventDefault="true"
    @onclick="OnLabelClick"
    class="@Class w-full group flex @(Disabled ? "cursor-default" : "cursor-text") flex-wrap gap-2  text-base">

    <!-- User pills -->
    @if (Value is not null && Value.Count > 0)
    {
        @foreach (var user in Value)
        {
            <UserMultiSelectPill Disabled="@Disabled" User="user.UserProfile" OnRemove="RemoveUser" ShowRemove="true"/>
        }
    }


    <!-- User Input -->
    <span class="flex items-center justify-start gap-0.5 relative ">
        <input
            @ref="_input"
            value="@_inputValue"
            @oninput="OnInputValueChanged"
            size="@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_inputValue) ? 1 : _inputValue.Length)"
            type="text"
            class="appearance-none border-none bg-transparent font-normal text-zinc-900 text-base font-extralight outline-none opacity-0 focus:opacity-100 focus:w-auto group-focus-within:opacity-100 w-0 group-focus-within:w-auto"
            @onkeydown="KeyboardEventHandler"
            disabled="@Disabled"/>
    </span>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <ul role="listbox" class="group-focus-within:block hidden absolute z-30 inset-x-0 top-full mt-2.5 min-h-[2.8rem] text-left max-h-60 w-full overflow-x-auto bg-white text-base rounded-lg shadow focus:outline-none">
        <!-- Dropdown options -->
        @if (!IsFilteringUsers)
        {
            @if (FilteredUsers.Count > 0)
            {
                @foreach (var user in FilteredUsers)
                {
                    <li role="option" class="text-zinc-900 hover:text-blue-400 active:text-blue-500 sm:text-sm hover:bg-slate-50 active:bg-slate-100 px-4 py-3 border-b border-slate-100 active:border-slate-200">
                        <button @onclick="() => SelectUser(user)" type="button"
                                class="w-full text-left truncate">
                            @user.FullName
                        </button>
                    </li>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <li class="px-4 py-3">
                    <p class="w-full text-center text-slate-500">Nothing found</p>
                </li>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <li class="px-4 py-3">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center mx-auto gap-2 text-center text-slate-500">
                    <Icon Type="IconTypes.Loader" Class="animate-spin text-md text-blue-400"/>
                    Loading ...
                </div>
            </li>
        }

    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there an alternative to using that group-focus-within class except writing custom JavaScript code for controlling display of the dropdown?